# How to check if a function is negligible?

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, computer-science

Let $\epsilon(x)$ be a [negligible function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_function). Let $p$ be a polynomial such that $p(k) \geq 0$ for all $k > 0$.

What can we say about $\epsilon(p(k))$? Is this a negligible function? If yes, then is there any formal or informal way to check whether a given function is negligible?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. You just need to substitute $x=p(k)$ in the definition of $\epsilon$ being a negligible function and check that the resulting function is negligible with respect to $k$. Did you try that? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Seems to be a pure mathematics question to me. That is, your failure to solve is not caused by lack of CS but of mathematics skill. Should I migrate this to [math.SE]? (Also, I think the Wikipedia article contains the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I was just cruising around and found this question (which I actually know answer for). Consider polynomial $p(n) = 1$ and negligible function $f(n) = 2^{-n}$. Then for constant $c=2$ there exists no $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall \ n \geq n_0$ it holds $\frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{n^2}$ (which is quite obvious). What helped here is the fact, that $f(p(n)) = \frac{1}{2}$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$.